# Inverse of perturbed matrix

Tags: matrices, inverse, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a positive definite matrix and $y$ be a vector.  Suppose we know $A^{-1}y$.  Is there an approximation algorithm for finding $(A + k^2 I)^{-1} y$ without having to invert any matrices, where $I$ is an identity matrix and $k$ is a scalar.

Comment: For small $k$, you have $(A+k^2I)^{-1} \approx A^{-1} (I-k^2A^{-1})$.

Comment: I suspect Pade approximations like this are probably the best you can do in general. This perturbation can be very large for ill-conditioned $A$. If you have some sort of spectral decomposition you can compute this exactly, which may be worth it if you need this for many values of $k$